# What does the last number in UNIX timestamp mean?

Tags: unix, timestamp

I have a few UNIX timestamps that I've been converting back and forth, and I notice that the last number of the timestamp would change without causing any difference in the date.

For example, if you convert this number to normal date:

```
1452120848 > 6-1-16 17:54
```

But if you convert it back:

```
6-1-16 17:54 > 1452120840
```

As you can see the last number was changed to a zero. I tried some of the online converters and discovered that the last number could be any number and the date wouldn't change. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unix time is the time in seconds since 1970.

You don't convert the seconds part of your date, thus it's 'lost' - your numbers may differ by up to 60.

The timestamp of `1452120848` is actually:  `Wed Jan  6 22:54:08 2016`

So you're missing 8 seconds.

Comment: So, there could be an error in the minutes if I don't convert the seconds, and the time is within 8 seconds of a new minute? Sorry if I can't explain myself too well, hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: No - if you don't convert the seconds, you round down to the nearest minute. You'd accomplish the same result by subtracting `$time % 60`.

Answer (score 1):

The UNIX timestamp gives you the seconds since 1st January 1970 00.00.00 UTC. Since this is seconds and you are just printing up to minutes, the difference is not shown.

However, they are not the same date:

```
$ date -d@1452120848
Wed Jan  6 23:54:08 CET 2016
$ date -d@1452120840
Wed Jan  6 23:54:00 CET 2016
```